# Opencv acceleration with CUDA in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu

I am HPC student and I have project coding by OpenCV functions and C++. I have to paralles the code for high performance, so I decide to use CUDA acceleration.  I confused with the following…

1. For getting a high performance , is it enough of using only CUDA?
2. Can I use both OpenCV::GPU or OpenCV::CUDA with Cuda GPU?
3. What is different between OpenCV::GPU and OpenCV::CUDA?

Answer (score 1):

1. CUDA programming can be only used if you have NVIDIA cards.  Power of General purpose GPU hardware will be utilized only if you do parallel processing.
   For example if you are working with images, every pixels of the images have individual operation.  Then GPU programming helps in saving you computation time.

   In your application second pixel input depends on first pixel input.  Then its better run your application in CPU itself.  Again data transfer from CPU to GPU and GPU to CPU will also affect performance.  Need to take care while you code.

2 & 3.  OpenCV2 versions syntax cv::gpu, whereas OpenCV3 version syntax is cv::cuda.   It depends on which opencv version you use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer actuually iam working on image localization and I  have aNvidia cards , so i just i want to  know if can I use both cuda and opencv::cuda in my application .

Comment: Yes.  That should not a be a problem.

Comment: I have another question, please. For my project, I need to compile CPU code with MinGW and open::cuda with MSVC compiler after I linking every thin together so do you know how can I do that on cmakelists.txt?

Comment: CUDA code will be compiled by nvcc complier.  Below are the few codes you may require in CMakeList.  

if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -Wall")
 set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
endif()
set(CUDA_HOST_COMPILER "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe")

Compiling a single application with two compilers(mingw & msvc) I never(taught) heard of.

Comment: I am a bit confused about that, this is my first time to  build a project in windows,  I will try to clarify the issue:
I have a  sequential code:that was writing by:c++(MinGW)+OpenCV+Qt+cmake
my task is to parallelize the code (porting to GPU):
so I decide to use Cuda (kernels) and after researching I found that I can also use a opencv::Cuda  to Parallelize OpenCV functions.

Now: I do not know how can I use both (Cuda kernels ) and (Opencv::cuda) in my application.what do you suggest to me?